# Why doesn't Content-Disposition header work in IE 8?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to stream a text file (CSV) to the response, and the following code works perfectly in Firefox 3, but when I use IE, it looks like it wants to download the actual .aspx page, and complains that the file contents don't match the file extension or type.  If I then choose to download the file anyway, it correctly downloads the CSV data and opens it in Excel.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    DataTable dt = ExtensionsProvider.ListPrivateCallCostsForCsv(reportFilter.BusinessUnit, reportFilter.StartDate,
                                                             reportFilter.EndDate);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + GetExportFileName()); 
    DataTableHelper.WriteCsv(dt, Response.Output, false);
    Response.End();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + GetExportFileName());
```

Should be:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + GetExportFileName());
```

Without a main `Content-Disposition` value, IE will just use the trailing part of the URL — `something.aspx` — as a filename.

(The above assumes `GetExportFileName()` returns a sanitised filename stripped of most punctuation. What can go in a header parameter as token or quoted-string in IE is a matter of some annoyance; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695356/downloading-file-with-or-in-file-name-ruins-filename/695719#695719) for details)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work with inline either. Of course it works for all other browsers

```
HttpServletResponse response = aCtx.getResponse();
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=log.txt");
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to give the value for the Content-Disposition header, in addition to the filename parameter.

You may have [more luck with the "inline" value](http://dotanything.wordpress.com/2008/05/30/content-disposition-attachment-vs-inline/) than the "attachment" value:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + GetExportFileName());
```