# Showing File name different in ie8 and in another browser using httpResponse header

Tags: java, http, adobe

I want a solution, MY problem is i have to show one pdf file.And when i save this file it should be save by a name which  is comming from request.getSession().getAttribute(Constants.Q_NO).I used following code .It is working for all browsers except ie8. when i execute my code in ie8 and press ..pdf button, it open  pdf file but when i try to save this file it save with a different name(name in my url like xyzController.pdf).I want it save with a name which is comming by a code request.getSession().getAttribute(Constants.Q_NO). So what a need to change and modify that it work for ie8 also.I read many senario for that but all are using attachment, in my senarion the requirement is different.
    The  code is below :

```
       response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", Constants.PUBLIC);
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", Constants.PUBLIC);
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
         "filename="+ request.getSession().getAttribute(Constants.Q_NO));
            System.out.println( request.getSession().getAttribute(Constants.QUOTE_NUMBER));
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be more with IE8 and it way to read the response header than with your java code.
Maybe this could help you (even if it's another language) :
[Why doesn't Content-Disposition header work in IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698308/why-doesnt-content-disposition-header-work-in-ie-8)

Comment: when i use attachment in header it work fine.it give correct name of file. But my requirement is different. I need  to  first open it in another window. inline also not working.  plz  suggest more solution