# Why does HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%20")) return + instead of %20?

Tags: asp.net, encoding, response

I'm having a problem with a file download where the download is replacing all the spaces with underscores.

Basically I'm getting a problem here:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
    "attachment; filename=" + someFileName);
```

The problem is that if someFileName had a space in it such as "check this out.txt" then the user would be prompted to download "check_this_out.txt".

I figured the best option would be to UrlEncode the filename so I tried

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(someFileName);
```

But it's replacing the spaces with plus signs, which stumped me.  So then I just tried

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%20"))
```

and the decode works properly and gives me a space, but the encode takes the space and then gives me the plus sign again.

What am I missing here, is this correct?  If so, how should I properly encode spaces into %20's, which is what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/cc3adbf7-2e77-4eea-92ee-53065dfc19cf/)

> I've come across this myself. If you
>   are able to change the spaces to %20s
>   then IE7 will convert them correctly.
>   Firefox though will take them
>   literally ( at least when using the
>   Content-disposition header) so you
>   will need to do this for requests from
>   IE7 only.
>
> We did the following in our app. ( a
>   tomcat based document repository)
>
> ```
> String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
> if (userAgent.contains("MSIE 7.0")) {
>     filename = filename.replace(" ", "%20");    
> }         
> response.addHeader("Content-disposition",
>     "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I found this in a different article elsewhere with the same solution as you have.  I'll probably end up having to do this, but it just feels wrong/dirty to me.  Oh well.

Answer (score 17):

Basically both %20 and + are valid ways of encoding a space. Obviously the UrlEncode method has to pick *one* of the options... if it chose to do the other way, someone else would have asked why `UrlEncode(UrlDecode("+"))` returned "%20"...

You could always encode it, then just do a straight string replace on "+" for "%20". I *think* that would work...

Comment: Thanks Jon.  The problem I'm seeing though, is that since it's choosing to go with the +, my file is showing up like "check+this+out.txt" instead of with spaces, which is the goal I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Joseph: as Jon said, " " is replaced by "+"; when you tries to escape "+", you'll go with "%2B"

Comment: @Rubens I understand, but that still doesn't solve my problem.  Either I encode it and my file ends up being called "check+this+out.txt" or I don't encode it and it gets called "check_this_out.txt".  How do I get it to properly show the white space?

Comment: Ok, so 5 years later, UrlEncode uses '+' but IIS 7 rejects '+' signs by default. What's the correct way to address this clash when creating URLs in server-side code? Do a second pass and replace the + signs with %20?

Comment: Thanks, I have also this problem with IE 11, and Jon's solution works for me. But Pay attention, first set the UrlEncoding, then the replace, like: 'Title.UrlEncoded.Replace("+", "%20")' works for me, but not 'Title.Replace("+", "%20").UrlEncoded'

Comment: "obviously the UrlEncode method has to pick one of the options": not at all.  There could be *and should be* a parameter allowing the *caller* to pick one of the options.

Comment: @phoog: To clarify, I meant *when using the given method signature*. I agree that it would be desirable to have options there.

Comment: @JonSkeet There ought to be a badge for "remembering why you wrote something after nine and a half years!" :-)

Answer (score 9):

> I figured the best option would be to UrlEncode the filename

That's not the right way to put out-of-band characters in a header parameter such as Content-Disposition-filename, and only works (sometimes) in IE due to a bug. Actually it's a bit of a perennial problem: [there is no right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695356/downloading-file-with-or-in-file-name-ruins-filename/695719#695719).

If you need to put special characters in the downloaded filename, you can't do it reliably with Content-Disposition-filename. Instead, omit the ‘filename’ parameter from the Content-Disposition-attachment header, and leave the filename you want in the trailing part of the URL. In the absence of a filename parameter the browser will take it from the URL path, where URL-encoding *is* the right way to tackle special characters.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I also faced same kind of problem when downloading the files having spaces in them.

Please see the link which best suites and gives the complete answer.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filenames_with_spaces_are_truncated_upon_download

For the sake of understanding I am just adding the ASP.net code how to solve this problem.

```
string document = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Gopal.Ampolu\My Documents\Downloads\" + "Disciplinary & Grievance Procedures..doc";
string filename = "Disciplinary & Grievance Procedures..doc";

Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", @"attachment; filename=""" + HttpUtility.UrlDecode(filename) + @"""");
Response.Flush();
```

**From the above you can see that while adding header to the response, filename is enclosed with double quotes.**
Please make sure that the "filename" must be Decoded with UrlDecode.

Answer (score 1):

One more option is also there, if you can intimate clients about windows hotfix update available at following:

[Windows Hotfix Update for IE white space issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952730)

It is client side, so may not be applicable to all the scenarios but still an option if feasible.