# eBay - Invalid Store Name

Tags: xml, ebay-api

When I request for "GetUserProfile" of Shopping API with user id "goneatr". I got Store name "New England Auto Truck Recyclers" as store name.

that's correct!! but, when I request "findItemsIneBayStore" of finding API with store name "New England Auto Truck Recyclers", I got Error

Failure

```
<error>
   <errorId>5</errorId>
   <domain>Marketplace</domain>
   <severity>Error</severity>
   <category>Request</category>
   <message>Invalid store name.</message>
   <subdomain>Search</subdomain>
   <parameter>New England Auto Truck Recyclers</parameter>
 </error>
```

Can anyone solve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a request to the eBay Shopping API with a store name, you need to make sure spaces in the Store Name param are converted to "+". So your request should include a param

```
&storeName=New+England+Auto+Truck+Recyclers
```

It's possible the client your making the API requests with is rendering them as " " or as "%20".

This is documented here: https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/findItemsIneBayStores.html#Samples

Comment: thanks Ellery !! I used HttpUtility.UrlEncode for encoding store Name.
what should I use?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561533/why-does-httputility-urlencodehttputility-urldecode20-return-instead-of) regarding converting "%20" to "+" with HttpUtility.UrlEncode