# S3 PutObjectRequest with non-ASCII Content-Disposition header throws exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I use the aws-sdk for java to upload a file to s3 (Frankfurt region).

```
ObjectMetadata omd = new ObjectMetadata();
omd.setContentDisposition("attachment;filename=\"" + someFileNameWithNonASCIIChars + "\"");
...
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, stream, omd);
```

[...](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html)

```
s3Object.putObject(por);
```

The last line throws a `AmazonServiceException` stating SignatureDoesNotMatch as the reason:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided.

This only happens when non-ASCII characters are in the Content-Disposition header value.

I am aware of the workaround for browsers that cannot handle utf-8 encoding decoding:

[How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http/20933751#20933751)

I can use this solution.
But is this the intended result from S3? 
Is there some way to send UTF-8 characters in the Content-Disposition header? And then I can just let the browsers deal with the non-ASCII characters.

Also, using the `*=utf-8''` workaround causes spaces to be decoded to "+" signs rather than back to spaces, which isn't ideal. It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561533/why-does-httputility-urlencodehttputility-urldecode20-return-instead-of/1561718?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But is this the intended result from S3?

Unfortunately, it is.  A long-standing issue with S3 prevents  signatures that are actually correct from being detected as correct when headers contain non-ascii characters, because the service actually calculates the signature incorrectly -- apparently the original design made the assumption that the utf-8 characters shouldn't be there... so utf-8 values can't be used.

For the `+` issue, just change those to `%20` after you do the encoding and they should work.  Any actual `+` in the filename before the encoding will appear in the encoded string as `%2B` so any remaining `+` is really a space.