# How to serve static file with a hebrew name in python bottle?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, bottle, static-files

I receive a request from the client to download some file from the server.
The filename is in Hebrew.

```
@bottle.get("/download/<folder_name>/<file_name>")
def download(folder_name, file_name):

    file_name =  file_name.decode('utf-8')
    folder_name =  folder_name.decode('utf-8')

    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(folder_name, file_name)):
        return bottle.static_file(file_name, root=folder_name, download=True)
```

The last line fails :

```
return bottle.static_file(file_name, root=folder_name, download=True)
```

I get an exception :

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 22-25: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have no idea what am i doing wrong here.

Callstack shows the exception derives from python bottle code:

```
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\bottle-0.10.9-py2.7.egg\bottle.py", line 1669, in __setitem__
  def __setitem__(self, key, value): self.dict[_hkey(key)] = [str(value)]
```

Please help.

Regard,
Omer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bottle is trying to set the `Content-Disposition` header on the HTTP response to `attachment; filename=...`. This doesn't work for non-ASCII characters, as Bottle handles HTTP headers with `str` internally... but then even if it didn't, there's no cross-browser-compatible way to set a `Content-Disposition` with a non-ASCII `filename`. ([Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695356/downloading-file-with-or-in-file-name-ruins-filename/695719#695719).)

You could set `download='...'` to a safe ASCII-only string to override Bottle's default guess (which is using the local filename, containing Unicode).

Alternatively, omit the `download` argument and rely on the browser guessing the filename from the end of the URL. (This is the only widely compatible way to get a Unicode download filename.) Unfortunately then Bottle will omit `Content-Disposition` completely, so consider altering the headers on the returned response to include plain `Content-Disposition: attachment` without a filename. Or perhaps you don't care, if the `Content-Type` is one that will always get downloaded anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line try encoding the unicode string into binary using `utf-8` codec:

```
return bottle.static_file(file_name.encode("utf-8"), root=folder_name.encode("utf-8"), download=True)
```

From the code you provided, it looks like the `bottle.static_file` method expects a string in binary format, therfore a default conversion using `ascii` codec is performed (as seen from the error message). As in your string you use Hebrew characters, which are not part of ascii, the default conversion fails. You need to use codec that supports national alphabets, like the `utf-8`.

For more information, see [Unicode In Python, Completely Demystified](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: can you please elaborate how to and what is the difference between that to the string encode I'm using

Comment: i'm using python 2.7 by the way

Comment: this doesnt work. there is no exception but the files are not found, getting a HTTPError(404, "File does not exist.")

Answer (score 0):

send_file parameters must be unicode.
Here is solution for bottle 0.5.8:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bottle import route, run, request, send_file, WSGIRefServer
@route('/:filename#.*#')
def static_file(filename):
    send_file(filename.decode('utf-8'), root=ur'g:\Folder')
run(server=WSGIRefServer, host='192.168.1.5', port=80)
```